# Production version iphone application crashes with "putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe"?

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging

My app runs successfully in a simulator,  but crashes when run on device with the following error:

```
putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe
putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run."
```

Are there known issues that can lead to this?

How can I debug this?

Comment: did you try to restart xcode & the phone? it happens sometimes when killing the app or removing the cable in the phone while xcode is running

Comment: yes I restart my device and facing again similar problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266784/putpkt-write-failed-broken-pipe visit it may be help to get solution !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to restart your device? This usually happens if you are at a breakpoint and you push the app to the background on the device by pressing the home button.

Comment: ok, so let's take this in reverse... What did you restart already? xcode, ipad, mac?

Comment: i restart xcode then i restart my ipod on which i was testing the app

Comment: Then, I'd reluctantly suggest to restart the Mac as well. This is obviously a software state issue so hopefully it would reset it.